# angularjs typeahead with enter event

Tags: angularjs

I want to display textbox with dropdown. when user enter text, it will call the function to access DB and returns list of users which match with entered text. that users list will be displayed in dropdown along with textbox like typeahead.

I am going to use angular typeahead for search users.
but my users list contains around 16000 data.
when i use typeahead, if I type a single character, it will call the async function,then all data will return filtered by that character.

So i would like to call that async function after user typed and press enter key.
Is there any other solution to achieve this?
or is there any other plugin for my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: angular typeahead: there is no such thing. **Which** typeahead?

Comment: Are you talking about angular ui typeahead? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Comment: I used typeahead-min-length attribute instead of enter.

Answer (score 0):

I have used typeahead-min-length attribute instead of enter functionality.